# How can I redefine a standard bookdown "theorem environment" in LaTeX/PDF?

Tags: bookdown

I am using `bookdown`, and would like the standard "example" and "definition" [environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems) (for example) in the PDF version to be more clearly distinguished by, for example, adding some slight background shading.

How do I do so? I cannot even find where these environments are defined (e.g. there is no definition in `preamble.tex`).

Yihui's book [says](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems)

> "If you are a LaTeX or HTML expert, you may want to customize
>   the style of these environments anyway (see Chapter 4). "

This implies it is possible. I have read that section, but I am still struggling (hence the post): clearly I am not an expert!

For example, just to test if what I am wanting to do is possible, I tried something really simple to begin with; I added this to `preamble.tex`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{example}
               {\begin{quote}}
               {\end{quote}}
\makeatother
```

The LaTeX compilation reports:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined.
```

So perhaps it isn't a standard environment at all. Indeed, the book implies perhaps it is a theorem. But I don't know how to redefine a theorem...

So is there a way to redefine these standard blocks for the PDF output (and if so, how)?

P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard blocks are environments, but they are defined *after* your custom preamble. Using `\AtBeginDocument` you can move your own changes past that definition:

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
      keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
- \AtBeginDocument{\renewenvironment{example}{\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}}
---

# Some section

```{example}
Here is my example.
```

```{definition}
Here is my definition.
```
````

Notes:

- I am using `header-includes` instead of `preamble.tex`, but that should not matter.
- `keep_tex: yes` is very helpful for analyzing things like this.
- These environments are created using the LaTeX package `amsthm`. It might offer more convenient hooks for customization.